# 'SUM()' in output map using SQL (Grails)

Tags: mysql, grails

In my MySQL Workbench, the following query works perfectly:

```
SELECT card.number, SUM(qty)
FROM card_set, card, user_card
WHERE card_set.id = card.card_set_id
AND user_card.card_id = card.id
AND card_set.id = 1
GROUP BY card.number ORDER BY card.number;
```

However, in my Grails controller, I have the following:

```
SELECT card.number, SUM(qty)" +
"FROM card_set, card, user_card\n" +
"WHERE card_set.id = card.card_set_id\n" +
"AND user_card.card_id = card.id\n" +
"AND card_set.id = 1\n" +
"GROUP BY card.number ORDER BY card.number;"
```

And the output is such:

```
[['number':1, 'SUM(qty)':2], ['number':2, 'SUM(qty)':3], ['number':3, 
'SUM(qty)':0], ['number':4, 'SUM(qty)':0], ['number':5, 'SUM(qty)':-2], 
['number':6, 'SUM(qty)':0], ['number':7, 'SUM(qty)':2], ['number':8, 
'SUM(qty)':2], ['number':9, 'SUM(qty)':0], ['number':10, 'SUM(qty)':0], 
['number':11, 'SUM(qty)':1], ['number':12, 'SUM(qty)':0], ['number':13, 
'SUM(qty)':1], ['number':14, 'SUM(qty)':1], ['number':15, 'SUM(qty)':2], 
['number':16, 'SUM(qty)':-1], ['number':17, 'SUM(qty)':0], ['number':18, 
'SUM(qty)':0], ['number':19, 'SUM(qty)':1], ['number':20, 'SUM(qty)':0]]
```

Why is Grails kicking out the text "SUM(qty)" to the Map List?  And how do I format it to NOT do that?

Answer (score 0):

The SQL API and protocol returns column header metadata with each result set. This is handy: it allows client software like Workbench and Grails to figure out the data type and the name of each column.

But for aggregate columns line `SUM(qty)` the MySQL server has to guess the name. The aggregate column doesn't have a column name from a table. It guesses, well, `SUM(qty)`.

If you change your query's first line to `SELECT card.number, SUM(qty) sum_qty` you'll get a nicer result, because you've told MySQL the name (in my example, `sum_qty`) you want to use for the column

Comment: Perfect!  Knew there was an easy answer ... Thanks